# Multiple applications in an Azure web app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Web API service currently sitting on an Azure Web app. It's used by mobile apps and have been thinking about how to do versioning as people might be using different version of the mobile app.

I've decided to do v1, v2 etc as different apps, so that when I move on to a new version I effectively freeze the previous version and not have to touch it at all.

One way of doing this is to create an sub application in my Azure Web App for each version, but have a few questions regarding this:

1. Do all apps within a Web App share the same app pool? If I deploy one using Team Services will it restart all the applications?
2. Is there just the one shared app config for all applications within in Web App? Using IIS each application would have it's own web.config but not sure if this is the case with Azure.
3. Not really a question, but in case anyone else was thinking of this route. By using applications for different versions means I won't be able to use slots unless I deploy every version each time, which I don't want to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do all apps within a Web App share the same app pool?

As far as I know, in Web Apps, each site and its child applications run in the same application pool. We could find detailed info at [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-migration-from-iis-server/#elements-verified-during-compatibility-analysis) .

> Is there just the one shared app config for all applications within in Web App? Using IIS each application would have it's own web.config but not sure if this is the case with Azure.

The application runs in its own directory with its own web.config. We could find the web.config files under each application directory via [Kudu console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) or App Service Editor.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. They do not.
2. They have separate.
3. I don't seem to understand the question. I believe you could upload different versions on the same app to different slots

"It's important to emphasize that the slot is in itself a regular Azure Web App, it will have its own app settings, connection string, any other configuration settings and even an scm site (https://mysite-staging.scm.azurewebsites.net).

In fact by default each Azure Web App has a single deployment slot called production which is the Azure Web App itself."

http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/11/azure-websites-slots/#.WCLqF_mcFEY

Comment: 2: How do I get to the separate config for an app? I can only see the main one. 3: If I have v1, v2, v3 and I only want to deploy v3 using slots, I'd have to deploy v1 & v2 for when I switch them

Comment: go to the yourapp.scm.azurewebsites.net and access the site directory, web config is there.

Comment: So it isn't supported using the Portal? These settings get overridden if I have them in the app config of the Portal, I would like to use the Portal only as it could get complicated managing many versions if I use the web.config

Comment: I don't think i understand the question again, you can swap using the portal. have you seen this https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/?

Comment: Yes, but that would swap all the applications in a Web App, not just one?

Comment: The applications are sub apps of a Web App. A slot switches at the Web App level, not application level so it would swap all of them